# How to add an material to the maya scene?

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

Hi everyone I am trying to write some script to automate my work in Maya.

Right now I am looking for the way to add materials to the **hypershade**.

I can't see anything on console (Script editor) so I can't se what python api I should use.

I know that maya treat materials as sets, and to assign a material to polygon I need to put it in this set, but I don't know how to create a new set.

So my question is:
**How I add a material to the scene using python maya-api?**

Comment: You can create sets with the `sets` command, look here: https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/sets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use createNode :

node = cmds.createNode('blinn', name='yipikai')

Comment: Thank to your answer I discovered that there is another way to this, by using cmds.shadingNode('name of the material', asShader=True). It worked for me. What the difference between createNode and shadingNode?

Comment: createNode is more broad where shadingNode is more centred around hyperShade and classify the node you are creating. I.E. : if you change the flag, you can create a blinn tagged either as shader, light, utility...